# Match anything except character unless it's followed by some other character

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I've got this odd string:

```
firstName:Paul Henry,retired:true,message:A, B & more,title:mr
```

which needs to be split into its `<key>:<value>` pairs. Unfortunately, key/value pairs are separated by `,` which itself can be part of the value. Hence, a simple string-split at `,` would not produce the correct result.

Keys contain only word characters and values can contain `:`.

What I need (I think) is something like

```
\w*:match-anything-but-comma-unless-comma-is-followed-by-space
```

What kind of works is

```
\w*:[\w ?!&%,]*(?![^,])
```

but of course I wouldn't want to explicitly list all characters in the character class (just listed a few for this example).

Comment: Can a value contain a colon?  (Example: `name:Terminator 2: Judgement Day,actor:Arnold Schwarzenegger`)  Can a key contain a comma?

Comment: Hhmm, good point. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Something like [this](http://regex101.com/r/mJ6eR3) ? Also what language are you using ?

Comment: Here's some input: `a:b,c:d,e`.  How do you know whether it should have one key/value (`a` and `b,c:d,e`) or two values (keys `a` and `c`, values `b` and `d,e`)?

Comment: @HamZa - You should make that an Answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to split on a comma, unless the comma is followed by a space, why not just:

```
,(?=\S)
```

Not sure what language you are using, but in C# the line might look like:

```
splitArray = Regex.Split(subjectString, @",(?=\S)");
```

Comment: I'm such a fool...I was soo sure the JavaScript `split` function doesn't accept a regex but your answer made me look it up in the docs again. It sure does.

Comment: Glad to help.  One way in JavaScript might be   result = subject.split(/,(?=\S)/);

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do something complicated with a regular expression that would be simple (and easy to understand) with a little code.  That's usually a mistake.  Just write a little code.

In your case, you want to split the input on commas.  If you get a chunk that doesn't contain a colon, you want to treat it as part of the previous chunk.  So just write that.  For example, in Python, I'd do it like this:

```
chunks = input.split(',')
associations = []
for chunk in chunks:
    if ':' in chunk:
        associations.append(chunk)
    else:
        associations[-1] += ',' + chunk

map = dict(association.split(':') for association in associations)
```